# Android ActionBar wrong layout direction

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-actionbar

I haven't worked with right to left layouts before, the application layout is forced rtl in the `AndroidManifest.xml` as follows:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl" ...>
    ...
</application>
```

But this is how the `ActionBar` shows up:

[image: ActionBar]

```
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:id="@+id/inventory_menu_drawer"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_18dp" />
  <item
    android:id="@+id/inventory_menu_search"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/action_drawer"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_18dp" />
</menu>
```

Shouldn't the items be nested from rtl or am i missing something? *I also checked the layout direction at runtime with `Window.Context.Resources.Configuration.LayoutDirection` and it returned `Rtl` and activity views are showing rtl OK as well.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The items have been laid out from right to left, but then left-justified. If you ran this code in left-to-right, you'd see the opposite. That is, the items would be laid out from left to right, but then right-justified. This is how the menu items work: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu

Comment: Oh man :\ So, is there anyway to change that or do i have to create a custom ActionBar?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for the Navigation Drawer pattern? https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html